# ReactJS - Delete Key Reverts to Value at onFocus

Tags: reactjs, numeric

I've got a long standing bit of JS which I use to turn an input into a Numeric.  This code works perfectly outside of ReactJS.

The code plugs into Key, Down, Up, Press events e.t.c. blocks alphas and applies min, max and precision on blur.

When I apply the same code to an input generated by ReactJS the delete and backspace keys change their behaviour.

When they're pressed, the value in the input will revert to whatever the value was when the input gained focus.

It's driving me crazy... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I've found a solution.  It was to implement and re-affirm the desired state during the onInput event via the setState method.

If you use JS to attach events via the a React Ref.  When that event finishes bubbling React will catch that at a higher document level and reapply the state.

I guess the lesson here is don't be lazy.  Integrate your components properly into a framework.